# How to add view controller objects to a mutable array?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to add some view controller objects to a mutable array. Below is my code.

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [_vc addObject:[self viewControllerAtIndex:0]];
    NSLog(@"VC Count is %lu",(unsigned long)[_vc count]));
}

- (UIViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{

    if (index == 0){
        QSG0Controller *QSG0Controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"QSG0Controller"];
        return QSG0Controller;
    }
    else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

And in the output window, it shows that VC count is 0.

Can anyone tell me why??? Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Are you sure this is the actual code you are running?

Comment: the original question indicates that there is a serious design pattern issue here. you don't need to store your view controller instances – the navigation stack does that for you; but if you don't want/need to push the view controller into the stack then you should not flood the memory with keeping unnecessary instances alive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need create `_vc` first. Try `_vc = [NSMutableArray new]` before `[_vc addObject:[self viewControllerAtIndex:0]];`